# After Generating webdriver code ,how and where to modify code

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, junit, selenium-webdriver

I am newbie to selenium test cases, my doubt roam between generated web driver code(java ;j-unit) and how to run that code with some changes in that code and found errors in the project

before that may i know where we want to made change in the code ,what we generated already.

For Eaxmple :

I recorded login form page, Generated Java/Junit 4/webdriver code with verify link button from selenium IDE and i import it as package into eclipse...

I add features or changes in that login form and i purpously forget to keep Link button

Using selenium test what i generated before as Java/Junit 4/webdriver code ,  i want to print O/P as"Link button not found"

```
   package web;
//import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
//import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
//import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class webdriver {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  //private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://localhost/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void testUntitled() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/CRM/Default.aspx");
    driver.findElement(By.id("LoginMain_UserName")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("LoginMain_UserName")).sendKeys("Admin");
    driver.findElement(By.id("LoginMain_Password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("LoginMain_Password")).sendKeys("xxx");
    try {
      assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.id("LoginMain_UserNameLabel")));
    } catch (Error e) {
      verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
    }
    try {
      assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.id("LoginMain_PasswordLabel")));
    } catch (Error e) {
      verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
    }
    try {
      assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.id("LoginMain_UserName")));
    } catch (Error e) {
      verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
    }
    try {
      assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.id("LoginMain_Password")));
    } catch (Error e) {
      verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
    }
    try {
      assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.id("LoginMain_LoginButton")));
    } catch (Error e) {
      verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
    }
    try {
      assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.id("LinkButtonRegister")));
    } catch (Error e) {
      verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
    }
    driver.findElement(By.id("LoginMain_LoginButton")).click();
    try {
      assertEquals("Webdriver Testingest.,", driver.getTitle());
    } catch (Error e) {
      verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
    }
    try {
      assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_ImageButton1")));
    } catch (Error e) {
      verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
    }
    try {
      assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_ImageButton2")));
    } catch (Error e) {
      verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
    }
    try {
      assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.linkText("Home")));
    } catch (Error e) {
      verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
    }
    try {
      assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.linkText("Sales")));
    } catch (Error e) {
      verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
    }
    try {
      assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.linkText("Masters")));
    } catch (Error e) {
      verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
    }
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);        
    }
  }

  private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
      driver.findElement(by);
      return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have bad news for you: Some basic understanding of Java and algorithms is needed to achieve that...

Comment: Set the message of the assert that checks the link button exists. Post your code so we can tell you where to make changes.

Comment: @PavelJanicek yep ur right .. i knpw basic java coding .. but dont know er to do the changes

Comment: @Morvader in command i used VerifyElementpresent for that link button

Comment: And i import that code as package in eclipse

Comment: Post the java generated code that verifies the element is present please

Comment: @Morvader Yes i posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get want you want you should modify:

```
try {
      assertTrue("Link button not found",isElementPresent(By.id("LinkButtonRegister")));
} catch (Error e) {
      //Add here any log message if necesary
      System.out.println("Link button not found");

      verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
}
```

Hope it help!

Comment: @user3563106 you have to modify the generated java code, the try/cath thats verifies that the link button is present

Comment: Thank you so much @Morvader!!!  Its the first time i excecuted... Where i want refer to improve my coding for this webdriver pls help me:)